# Resolve conflicting functions in R package DESCRIPTION file imports

Tags: r, build, compilation, package

I am trying to build an R package that depends on the following packages: `heatmaply`, `stats`, and `igraph`. I've created a `DESCRIPTION` file that includes the following:

```
Imports:
    heatmaply,
    stats,
    igraph
```

However, when I try to build, I'm getting the following warnings ("myPkg" is a placeholder for my actual package name here):

```
Warning messages:
1: replacing previous import 'heatmaply::normalize' by 'igraph::normalize' when loading 'myPkg' 
2: replacing previous import 'igraph::decompose' by 'stats::decompose' when loading 'myPkg' 
3: replacing previous import 'igraph::spectrum' by 'stats::spectrum' when loading 'myPkg'
```

Notably, I'm not actually using any of the conflicting functions. But because the entire package is listed as a dependency, the conflicts are an issue. Is there an elegant way to solve this? I know that I can use `import::from()` inline to import only the functions I need, but I prefer not to do that because inline imports are considered poor practice.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I was able to fix it by doing the following:

- Removing all `@import` statements at the beginning of the functions I defined.
- Including `pkgName::` before each function call.